# Apply function in R generates missing value error

Tags: r, apply

I admit I'm an R beginner so apologies in advance for a basic question. I am following this guide in an attempt to run a log linear analysis on data with three or more factors using my own dataset:
https://mgimond.github.io/Stats-in-R/ChiSquare_test.html

I am stuck on the part where you create a matrix from your dataset using the 'apply' function. I have three factors:

- ONS_ONL (whether the person's location is ONS or ONL)
- OffVar (whether the person took their course at the same location or
  an offsite location)
- FailVar (whether the person failed or passed their course)

Running str() on my data generates the following:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   775 obs. of  3 variables:
$ ONS_ONL: Factor w/ 2 levels "ONL","ONS": 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 ...
$ OffVar : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
$ FailVar: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

And opening the table to view produces the following:
[Click to view table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTiOi.png)

The guide recommends using the 'apply' to convert your data into a data matrix, which is supposed to aggregate counts by each factor. But I get this result when attempting to run it:

```
matrix <- apply(data,c(1:3),sum)
Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I've searched around but can't find the cause of this error. There doesn't seem to be any NULLS in the data based on the str() function. Can anyone help?

Comment: You have a data frame; the examples with Titanic are different, as that is a multi-dimensional array. If you keep reading the guide carefully, there are notes about how to convert back and forth between the two, in your case probably with `xtabs()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out - I completely overlooked it when reading the example. xtabs() fixed my issue!